Top Cómic Español
Hace unos días se planteaba esta pregunta que supongo que será cerrada porque las posibles respuestas serán subjetivas o basadas en opiniones, o porque es off-topic. En ella se requerían recomendaciones de cómics españoles (editados en España, con guión y dibujo de españoles, supongo). Como amante del cómic y usuario de los distintos sitios de StackExchange, considero que debería existir una pregunta así donde cada respuesta fuera un cómic clásico o muy recomendable y donde los usuarios pudieran votar de forma que se convirtiera en una lista de lectura recomendada colaborativa. También se podría ampliar el ámbito para que abarcara comic producido en otros países hispanohablantes.
¿Se podría hacer ese tipo de listado aquí en meta y tenerlo enlazado en la home del sitio principal?

@Megustalafruta Muy constructivo. No veo cuál es el problema en hacer esas listas. La que yo propongo responde a una pregunta concreta. ¿No está este sitio dedicado a eso?

@Megustalafruta ¿pero porque hacer todos esos listados cuando tanto el OP de la pregunta que enlazo como yo hablamos solo de cómics? Lo suyo es una propuesta distinta, que me parece estupenda pero no es la mía.

https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german se puede hacer una pregunta canónica, ni siquiera es necesario enlazar nada

@tac Interesante. Gracias por el enlace y la idea
